# Linux: find - Stop as soon as it finds something

Tags: linux, find

I am trying to use find to locate a single directory, and I would like it to stop as soon as it finds something, is this possible?

Currently I am using the command `find /directory/to/search/ -maxdepth 4 -name *search_text* -type d -prune`  Which cuts the run time down a decent amount but it still continues for a while after it finds what I am looking for.  Since this is being run in a script I can't simply <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> to stop it.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure just run

```
find /directory/to/search/ -maxdepth 4 -name "*search_text*" -type d -prune -print -quit
```

check out the man page for find and its *actions* section

Comment: That's perfect! I don't know how I missed this in the man page. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
find ... | head -1
```

As soon as head has read one line it will close the pipe which will kill the find.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's directly possible; find doesn't have any option for it.

I found [this snippet](http://fixunix.com/unix/83318-limit-find-one-file.html) which kills find when it reaches the second result:

```
find /directory/to/search/ -name *search_text* -print -exec perl -e 'kill "INT", getppid' \;
```